# How to create a cardview with "slide" (similar to Nubank)?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to make a layout similar to `cardview` from nubank's main screen, however, I'm not able to find reference to base myself. What I'm having trouble finding, is like leaving the `cardview` with these `dots`. Can anyone point me some material, or even give me tips on how to do?

Sorry for my English

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it, and I ended up answering my own question in Stack Overflow in Portuguese.

How I did it: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345597/57664

Answer (score 0):

I'd do that with a ViewPager and every fragment would have a CardView as the root.
The rounded border of the CardView is about 4dp and set the ViewPager pageMargin to be about 16dp.

About the dots... It is a page indicator
There's is this [one](https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView)
and many others, like this other [one](https://github.com/DavidPacioianu/InkPageIndicator)

This might give you the NuBank card effect